# enable subscription in DolphinDB

Tags: subscribe, dolphindb

I deployed a single node in DolphinDB and was trying function `subscribeTable`. I got the following error message:

```
Can't complete subscription because subscription is not enabled.
```

How can I enable subscription in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

As you use the single node mode of DolphinDB, you need to specify configuration parameters `subPort` and `maxPubConnections` in the configuration file. For examples:

```
subPort=80001
maxPubConnections=6
```